# How is this jQuery plugin loading data? Can't tell from Firebug

Tags: javascript, debugging, jquery-plugins, firebug

I'm working with this jQuery plugin, and watching it save and load data using Firebug (beware, the author has chosen to demo it with pics of scantily-clad women, possibly NSFW): http://www.bennadel.com/resources/projects/jquery_photo_tagger/demo/

I want to work out how the page is loading tags. I'm confused, because the plugin specifies URLs for saving and loading data (`save_Tag.cfm` and `load_tags.cfm`). Indeed, when I save a tag, I can 'see' the data being sent off to `save_Tag.cfm` in Firebug.

However, when I reload the page, Firebug shows the response from `load_tags.cfm` as empty - yet the tag is still loaded.

See the [actual plugin code](http://www.bennadel.com/resources/projects/jquery_photo_tagger/demo/phototagger.jquery.js) for more details.

Please could anyone explain how the page is loading tags, and also, how I can see this data using either Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools?

Thanks very much!

Comment: nice pictures! ;) -- almost nsfw

Comment: oh yeah - the guy obviously likes, erm, muscular women :-/ I've edited the question to warn people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the firebug "Net" tab. Sometimes the requests doesn't appear in the console, and in these cases you can use the "Net" tab (the last one from the tab selector).

In Chrome or safari you can also use the "Network" tab. Here select the option "XHR" to see the Ajax requests.

Comment: Yep, I was doing that already (sorry if it's not clear). The problem is that the Net tab shows an empty response from `load_tags.cfm`, hence my confusion.

Comment: When I inspect both with chrome or firefox i get this:
      Request URL: http://www.bennadel.com/resources/projects/jquery_photo_tagger/demo/save_Tag.cfm?_=1297636205585&id=&x=326&y=238&width=1&height=1&message=thetag&photoID=photo3
Response:
"21251C94-FFAE-1669-D1DB125A5CAEA462"

Answer (score 0):

When I inspect the initial load in Firebug I get this response:

```
[{"ID":"11033514-FFAE-1669-D1E0F669C6480F74","PHOTOID":"photo3","Y":179.0,"WIDTH":1.0,"HEIGHT":1.0,"MESSAGE":"blah","X":290.0}]
```